# Is there a way to edit RPGLE program from CL command without opening RPGLE program?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a RPGLE program as below which has tags `AD11` for date `220318` , but for other dates like `220317` and `220323` there are no tags. Is there any CL command that can insert `AD11` tag for other two dates ? Or is there any program that can be written to insert tags if there is no tag present in position 1 to 4, based on the dates fed as input parameter?

Program showing tags `AD11` for `220318`

[image]

Any suggestions/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: This does not answer you question and you probably already know it, but seeing your code that uses modern syntax that SEU doesn't know, searching for lines changes at a specific date, and add some comment that looks like a version tag, I think the best suggestion one can give is drop SEU and sources in members, use ifs files, some modern editor (RDI, vscode,  ...) and use a real change tracking system like git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CL can't do this specifically but what you could do is embed SQL within CL or just run SQL directly via "STRSQL".

n.b. SQL has no concept of members so if the file containing your RPGLE source member has multiple members you'll need to override to that member before running your script.

An example CL program would look like this;

```
             PGM                                                             
                                                                         
             /* Override file name "QRPGLESRC" to "MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.SRCMBR" */
             OVRDBF     FILE(QRPGLESRC) TOFILE(MYLIB/QRPGLESRC) +          
                          MBR(SRCMBR) OVRSCOPE(*JOB)                       
                                                                         
             /* Update "MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.SRCMBR" */                           
             RUNSQL     SQL('UPDATE QRPGLESRC +                              
                                SET SRCDTA = ''AD11'' || SUBSTR(SRCDTA,5) +  
                              WHERE SRCDAT = 220408') +                      
                        COMMIT(*NONE)                                        
                                                                         
             /* Remove previous override */                                  
             DLTOVR     FILE(QRPGLESRC) LVL(*JOB)                            
                                                                         
             ENDPGM
```

Answer (score 1):

Since source members are stored in files, you can create a HLL (RPG or COBOL) program to modify the data in the source member.

Comment: Not just RPG or COBOL, but anything which can update the built-in Db2 database. This would include SQL in a number of host languages, such as CL, Python, and Node.js (JavaScript), just to name a few that are included or available for free on the i. You could certainly also update the database (and thus edit source members) from machines that can connect to the i (via ODBC or JDBC, for example), which opens up the choice of programming language to just about anything you can think of.

Comment: @JohnY true, but working with members in SQL takes a bit more work. In a HLL language, you can easily do an OVRDBF.

Comment: "More work" and "easily" are largely subjective. I find it easier to pick out a member in SQL via alias (single line of code in the same source as the rest of my SQL code) than to do an override (traditionally done with one extra line in the calling CL program, which is in a different source than my HLL code; or perhaps could also be done with an API like QCMDEXC within the HLL code, but which would add several lines when you include the PARMs or prototype). Not saying that the override approach is hard or a lot of work, but to me it is "a *bit* more work" than doing it all in SQL.